# How can I override this Swift property?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class Base: UIViewController {
    var rightButtonColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}


class SecondViewController: Base {    
    override var rightButtonColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.redColor() 
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Getter for 'rightButtonColor' with Objective-C selector
>   'rightButtonColor' conflicts with getter for 'rightButtonColor' from
>   superclass 'Base' with the same Objective-C
>   selector

Comment: You simply cannot override a read-write property with a read-only property. A key rule of OOP is that you can always pass a subclass to anything that expects its superclass. To the thing that expects the superclass, your property is read-write – but it isn't if you pass in the subclass. Note that if you reversed this example (trying to override a read-only property with a read-write property), it would work (although your read-write property would have to be a calculated one as you can't introduce storage in an override).

Answer (score 7):

Try like this:

```
class Base: UIViewController {
    var rightButtonColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}

class SecondViewController: Base {
    override var rightButtonColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The two different declarations of `rightButtonColor` have different types.  It compiles cleanly if you make sure they're the exact same type:

```
class Base: UIViewController {
    var rightButtonColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}

class SecondViewController: Base {
    override var rightButtonColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```